# Week starting date from date in an older version of Presto

Tags: presto

I have a somewhat straightforward problem, where I'm trying to find the week starting date (Sunday) for a given date in Presto. Normally I'd try

```
DATE_FORMAT(date(DateID),'%X%V') as WeekStartingDate,
```

But the 0.144 documentation I'm using says [they're not currently supported](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.144/functions/datetime.html). An approach I used in a MySQL environment was something like

```
DATE_ADD(DateID, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(DateID)) DAY)
```

But Presto doesn't have the `DAYOFWEEK` function. I've also tried doing

```
concat( cast(year(DateID) as varchar) , cast(week(DateID) as varchar)) as WeekStartingDate,
```

But the issue there is the data isn't sorted correctly. I'll get 20201 next to 202010 for example. Are there any recommended solutions I'm not thinking of?

Comment: You're referring to Presto docs for v 0.144. Here is the up to date link - https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
date_trunc('week', date(DateID))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `lpad` in your second 2nd try:

```
concat( cast(year(DateID) as varchar) , lpad(cast(week(DateID) as varchar),2,'0') ) as WeekStartingDate,
```

This will end up with `202001, 202002...., 202010, 202011, etc..` that is nicely sorted.